# Exclude (not set) in RGoogleAnalytics filters

Tags: r

I am running an R script with the highlighted following filter:

```
query.list <- Init(start.date = as.character(startdate),
               end.date = as.character(enddate),
               dimensions = 
"ga:date,ga:campaign,ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:adGroup,ga:adDestinationUrl",
               metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:bounces",
               max.results = 10000,
               **filters = 
c("ga:adwordsCampaignID!=%28not%20set%29;ga:sessions>0"),**
               table.id = example)

ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

x <- as.integer(difftime(max(as.Date(query.list$end.date, '%Y-%m-%d')) , 
min(as.Date(query.list$start.date, '%Y-%m-%d')) , units = "days"))
# Daywise split paramter defaults to False when date does not equal Monday
daywisesplit <- if(x == 0) {
  F
}   else {
  T
}
# Extract the data and store it in a data-frame
example_camp <- GetReportData(ga.query, token, split_daywise = daywisesplit)
example_camp$date <- as.Date(example_camp$date, '%Y%m%d')
example_camp$brand <- 'Example'
example_camp <- subset(example_camp, sessions > 0)
example_camp <- subset(example_camp, adwordsCampaign > 0)
```

The Script runs with no errors, but when looking into the `write.csv` file I continue to see the (not set) within the `AdwordsCampaignID` column. Moreover, when I look at the sessions column all the columns with zero sessions are not included, so this filter is working properly.

**How can I make the exclude (not set) filter work properly when pulling data into the the write.CSV?Perhaps I need to update the data-frame?**

Comment: You need to show more code. What you posted is not really enough. However there seems to be an extra comma after the `c()` function. Also there is no reason to use it if there is only one string. As far as the `write.csv()` it will write whatever is in the data frame so you will have to filter it *before* you write.

Comment: I added more of my script per your request.